# How can I let Ionic know about the change of the project structure?

Tags: cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, project-structure, directory-structure

I have changed the internal "www" folder structure, i.e., moved "scss" folder to a folder "assets", created an "app" folder, etc. Now, when I am trying to run:

`ionic setup sass` (http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html),

it creates a "css" folder in "www" but not "www/assets".

How can I update Ionic on structural changes? I have managed to update ".bowerrc" so it knows where to put packages, but it is only Bower that is aware of the new project structure.

[image: "www" Structure]

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if you think it solved your issue :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use whatever folder you want for your css files.
One thing you have to change is the gulp task in the **gulpfile.js**:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});
```

As you can see it transforms the **scss** file **ionic.app.scss** in the destination folder `./www/css/`

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
```

That's the bit of code you have to change with the new path.

Don't forget to change your **index.html** with the new path as well:

You don't have to change the ionic.project file as it already includes all the files in the **www** folder (and subfolders) excluding **www/lib** (and subfolders); see [ref](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli):

> LiveReload
>
> By default, LiveReload will watch for changes in your www/ directory,
>   excluding www/lib/.

UPDATE:

Maybe someone is interested to change the root folder `www`. We can do that but we have to instruct ionic to use a different name.

ionic.project has got an additional property: `documentRoot`:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "documentRoot": "app",
  "gulpStartupTasks": [
    "sass",
    "watch"
  ],
  "watchPatterns": [
    "app/**/*",
    "!app/lib/**/*"
  ]
}
```

[Serving an alternate document root](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/master/README.md#serving-an-alternate-document-root) give more info on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I have to also modify "ionic.project" file? To: `"watchPatterns": [ "www/assets/**/*", "!www/assets/lib/**/*"]`.

Comment: Yes if you want the `ionic serve` task to use live reload correctly with the sass files in your project. It watches the files in this pattern array for changes and triggers a sass rebuild automatically.

Comment: @Arthur: actually, no as it already contains everything in www excluding www/lib

Comment: @JeremyWilken: you're right. Forgot to mention that. Thanks.

Comment: Is it also possible to rename the root folder of the app like `www` -> `app`?

Comment: @uloco: You can do whatever you want as long as you change references in your `index.html` and `gulpfile.js`.

Comment: But I added the watchPatterns and `ionic serve` still points to `www`to find the `index.html` file

Comment: Please, you can answer here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/rename-project-root-www-to-app/34163

Comment: @uloco: I've extended the answer here as well. Cheers.

Comment: For others, keep in mind that running ```ionic update``` will still install ionic resources in the www/lib directory. So, you'll have to move them after an update.